# Ping-Timestamp in Batchfile won't proceed after -n is finished

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, ping

i have a problem with my batchfile:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
set ip=192.168.1.1
:lp
set log=C:\Elvis-Log\LOG_%date:~-10,2%.%date:~-7,2%.%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%.txt
ECHO New Log
ECHO Elvis-Server Ping-Test auf %ip% - IPR/S Linie 5.5 >> %log%
ECHO. >> %log%
echo %date:~0% - %time:~0,8% Uhr >> %log%
ping -n 86400  %ip%|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!time! !data!)&ping -n 2 %ip%>nul" >> %log% 
ECHO. >> %log%
GOTO lp
```

I have a server for my knx visualization system "Elvis". 
Now i want to constantly ping to one of my IP-routers and log the results.
Every 24 hours a new Logfile should be created, with the actual date and time as name.
The creation of the Logfile works fine.

Now i want a timestamp on every single ping so i can tell when exactly the network had timeouts.

```
ping -n 86400  %ip%|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!time! !data!)&ping -n 2 %ip%>nul" >> %log% 
ECHO. >> %log%
```

This should do the job, but after -n expires it just stops logging but dont creates a new logfile.
A simple ping without the timestamp thing works just fine.

If possible i dont want to use external Software.

I'm pretty new to Batch Programming... and Programming at all, i hope someone can help me here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you need just time when the connection status *changes*, you should let the script do the work for you instead of manually checking a big file.

```
@echo off
set ip=www.google.com
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set oldstatus=unknown
:loop
ping -n 1 -w 500 %ip% |find "TTL" >nul && set "status=online" || set "status=offline"
if not %oldstatus%==%status% (
  echo %time:~0,8%: went %status%
  set "oldstatus=%status%"
)
goto :loop
```

this gives an output only, when the status changes.

Comment: The `ping -n 86400` means 60*60*24, a whole day. I would create a schedule for that, I prefer your idea of state changes, but I'd include a `timeout -t 59` eventually with `>Nul` appended.

Comment: @LotPings: yes, generally a `timeout` is a good idea. Depends on what resolution is needed. A resolution of a whole minute will probably hide most outages. The original script is designed to produce a new logfile every 24 hours. As my suggestion produces *much* less data, probably this isn't needed. You can also "fine tune" the resolution with `ping`s `/w` parameter. And yes, if this should run for days or even weeks, a scheduled task is surely helpful (also for periodically producing a new logfile)

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code uses a method to generate the timestamp that was written with a severe limitation: to be a one-liner as it was intended to be used from command line.

That led to a infinite `ping` being read in an infinite loop as while reading from a pipe the `set /p` can not differentiate from

- an empty/blank line,
- a read operation that not retrieves anything (input stream empty),
- the end of the input stream.

That is the reason your command does not end, the `for /l` keeps looping as it does not know when the command on the left ends.

But you can add an exit condition, you can include something like

```
if not "%date%"=="!date!" exit
```

that is, if the `%date%` value (values references as `%var%` are expanded once when the command is parsed) does not match the current `!date!` value (`!var!` referenced values are expanded each time the command is executed), leave the loop (the commands inside the pipe are running in a separate `cmd` instance, we leave the instance)

That leaves another problem, you can leave the loop, but the `ping` will continue sending packets, independently of the `cmd` reading the output.

This can be solved if we first determine how many packets we need to send before the end of the day and adding a timeout in the packet sent to avoid problems if packets are lost (the default timeout is 4000ms)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "ip=192.168.1.1"

:lp
    set "log=C:\Elvis-Log\LOG_%date:~-10,2%.%date:~-7,2%.%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%.txt"
    set /a "nPings= 86401 - (%time:~0,2% * 3600 + %time:~3,2% * 60 + %time:~6,2%)"

    >>"%log%" (
        ECHO Elvis-Server Ping-Test auf %ip% - IPR/S Linie 5.5
        ECHO(
        echo %date:~0% - %time:~0,8% Uhr
        ping -w 1000 -n %nPings%  %ip% | cmd  /v /q /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!time! !data!) & ping -n 2 "" >nul & if not "%date%"=="!date!" exit " 
        echo(
    )
GOTO lp
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your code works like a charm! Also very informative explanation!